# What are the general zonal spherical functions for ${\rm SO}(n)/{\rm SO}(n-1)$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, polynomials

The zonal spherical functions [1] on the sphere $(G={\rm SO}(n)$, $K={\rm SO}(n-1))$ are the Gegenbauer or ultraspherical polynomials if one considers the irreducible representations of ${\rm SO}(n)$ corresponding to traceless symmetric tensors. Are they also known for tensor irreps of ${\rm SO}(n)$ with mixed symmetry (Young diagrams with multiple rows)?

Alternatively, do you know a reference to an explicit calculation showing that the zonal spherical functions for symmetric irreps on ${\rm SO}(n)/{\rm SO}(n-1)$ are the Gegenbauer polynomials?

Since $({\rm SO}(n), {\rm SO}(n-1))$ is a Gelfand pair, is the zonal spherical function for some ${\rm SO}(n)$ irrep given by the corresponding character integrated over ${\rm SO}(n-1)$?

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zonal_spherical_function

Comment: See this paper Daniel Barlet Jean-Louis Clerc . there is a nice asymptotic formula for Zonal functions,
Le comportement à l'infini des fonctions de Bessel généralisées, I
. Advances in Mathematics
Volume 61, Issue 2, August 1986, Pages 165-183 .https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870886900733 . Note that $ SO(n)/SO(n−1)\cong S^{n-1}$